# Strongly typed form fields in Play Framework views

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

We have to use the property name as a string to render an HTML field in Play Framework views:

Scala:

```
case class MyClass(myField: Int)
```

View:

```
@(form: Form[MyClass])
...
@helper.inputText(form("myField"), '_label -> "Field Title")
```

This is not **strongly typed**!

So Is there any way to mention field names in a strongly typed manner? 
like this:

```
@helper.inputText(form(model => model.myField), '_label -> "Field Title")
```

I'm sure that this is possible in Scala but fortunately we have macros and such code can be implemented without any runtime overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think about the string as the name of the property but rather the form field id/name which *is* a string, since Form models a form and not primarily an object (it is possible and even very useful to model forms with tuples as data structures for example). This is indeed strongly typed as you cannot send anything but a string in there.

Your problem though is that you would like to use the type system even more, to encode the actual values as types or something that to avoid spelling something wrong etc.

I think you have a few approaches you could take, with various gains and problems:

- Write your own form api and use the type system to identify field ids somehow
- Enforce using constants as keys in your project, not by using the type system but just decide to do it that way
- Write your own wrapper for the form builder and the form helpers accepting some more restricted type as keys
- Represent your model field as some kind of "property" type and combine that with custom wrappers for the form builder and form helpers.

Neither of these is really built into play, and all but the constants approach will have you write more or less complicated code so you will have to weigh this in with what the actual gains of solving this problem is worth to you.

Good luck!